# Magento RWD and Gulp

Tags: frontend, rwd

I'm trying to work with the new RWD theme, but i'm not happy with compass watch, as it is very slow and I can't find my way around it.

Dose any one know how to use gulp instead? my main problem with the import path it didn't work and I keep getting errors.

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
  var stream = gulp
    .src(['scss/styles.scss'])
    .pipe(compass({
        import_path: '../../../rwd/default/scss',
        css: 'css',
        sass: 'scss',
        image: 'src/images'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../css'));

  if (config.minifyCss === true) {
    stream.pipe(minifycss({keepSpecialComments: '0'}));
  }

  return stream
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../css'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Successfully compiled SASS' }));
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did fix it, and here how if any one want to follow

**config.rb**

```
# REQUIRE ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# require 'compass/import-once/activate'
# require 'breakpoint'
# require 'susy'

# PROJECT PATHS ---------------------------------------------------------------

http_path = "/skin/frontend/custompackage/customtheme/src"
css_dir = "../css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "../images"
javascripts_dir = "../js"
relative_assets = true

# FRAMEWORKS -------------------------------------------------------------------
# Additional path

add_import_path "../../../rwd/default/scss"

# SPRITES & IMAGES -------------------------------------------------------------
# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:

relative_assets = true

# OUTPUT -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):

output_style = :expanded # :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed
environment = :development # :production or :development

# SASS -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:

line_comments = false # true or false
cache = true # true or false
color_output = false # required for mixture
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "~3",
        "gulp-bless": "~1.0",
        "gulp-compass": "^1.3.2",
        "gulp-cache": "^0.2.0",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.3.3",
        "gulp-jshint": "^1.7.1",
        "gulp-sass": "~0.7.1",
        "gulp-livereload": "^2.1.0",
        "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.6",
        "gulp-notify": "^1.4.0",
        "gulp-rimraf": "^0.1.0",
        "gulp-uglify": "^0.3.1",
        "gulp-plumber": "latest",
        "bower": "~1.3.5"
    }
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
// Load plugins
var
  gulp         = require('gulp'),
  compass      = require('gulp-compass'),
  sass         = require('gulp-sass'),
  minifycss    = require('gulp-minify-css'),
  uglify       = require('gulp-uglify'),
  // rename          = require('gulp-rename'),
  rimraf       = require('gulp-rimraf'),
  concat       = require('gulp-concat'),
  notify       = require('gulp-notify'),
  cache        = require('gulp-cache'),
  livereload   = require('gulp-livereload'),
  // plumber      = require('gulp-plumber'),
  path         = require('path');

var config = {

  // If you do not have the live reload extension installed,
  // set this to true. We will include the script for you,
  // just to aid with development.
  appendLiveReload: true,
  // Should CSS & JS be compressed?
  minifyCss: true,
  uglifyJS: true

}

// css
gulp.task('css', function() {
  var stream = gulp
    .src(['scss/styles.scss'])
    .pipe(compass({
        config_file: 'config.rb',
        css: '../css',
        sass: 'scss',
        image: '../images'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../css'));

  if (config.minifyCss === true) {
    stream.pipe(minifycss({keepSpecialComments: '0'}));
  }

  return stream
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../css'))
    //.pipe(notify({ message: 'Successfully compiled LESS' }));
});
```

Thanks https://github.com/webcomm/magento-boilerplate there gulp file was very helpfull.